# С++ вывод столбцами через cout

Tags: c++, консоль, fstream

Есть такая задача: сгенерировать матрицу NxN случайными числами, найти в каждом столбце полученной матрицы максимум, из выборки максимумов найти минимум. Поначалу пришло такое, вроде как, простое решение:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <conio.h>

#define N 6
#define RAND() rand() % 100 // [0;99]
#define SIZE setw(4)

using namespace std;

ofstream fout("result.txt");

void print(const char* str)
{
    cout << str;
    fout << str;
}

void print(int number)
{
    cout << SIZE << number;
    fout << SIZE << number;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    int d2arr[N+1][N]; // доп строка для максимумов столбцов
    int min = 100;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        d2arr[N][i] = -1;

    print("Вывод сгененированной матрицы:\n");

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
        {
            d2arr[i][j] = RAND();
            if (d2arr[i][j] > d2arr[N][j])
                d2arr[N][j] = d2arr[i][j];
            print(d2arr[i][j]);
        }
        print("\n");
    }
    print("\nВывод максимумов для столбцов:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        if (d2arr[N][i] < min)
            min = d2arr[N][i];
        print(d2arr[N][i]);
    }
    print("\n\nМинимум из выборки:");
    print(min);
    fout.close();

    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

однако хотелось бы оптимизировать программу и избавиться от второго цикла, идея такая (псевдо):

```
int min = 100, max=-1;
int d2arr[N][N];
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
        {
            d2arr[j][i] = RAND(); // генерируем по столбцам
            if (d2arr[j][i] > max)
                max = d2arr[j][i];
            print(d2arr[j][i]);
        }
        if (max < min) min = max;
        print("\n");
    }
```

Собственно проблема: как выводить сразу же такие данные? Допустим я выведу первый столбец, перенося строку после каждого элемента. Как вернуться к началу консоли? Желательно без консольхендлей и SetConsoleCursorPosition, а с использованием чего-то попроще (простая универовская лаба, просто интересно сделать по-другому).
**P.S.:** в программе используется fstream, и там должно выводиться тоже самое.
OS винда, Visual studio

Comment: "... однако хотелось бы оптимизировать программу ..." Ым... Никакого смысла в такой "оптимизации" нет. И оптимизации в этом тоже никакой нет.  Лучше было бы сделать наоборот: сделать больше циклов. Один цикл - только генерация, никакого вывода. Еще один цикл - вывод сгенерированной матрицы. Еще цикл - анализ матрицы. Пусть каждый цикл решает самостоятельную задачу. И вынести их в отдельные функции.

Comment: И в чем смысл такой оптимизации?

Comment: Это не "оптимизация", это чисто стилистика и грамотная организация кода. Каждый блок/этап кода решает лишь *одну*, свою задачу. Такой код намного легче читать, намного легче отлаживать, намного легче обслуживать, намного легче переиспользовать. Список можно продолжить.

Comment: И чем это лучше? У меня будет один цикл, который делает сразу три задачи и пробегает по матрице 36 раз, или у меня будут три цикла, которые будут выполнять те же три задачи, но бегать по матрице 36*3 раз. И сколько еще потерь на операциях сравнения всех этих циклов

Comment: Я уже написал выше, чем это лучше. А учитывая, что ваша программа приведена здесь *целиком* и занимается вводом-выводом (!), сама "беготня по матрице" в вашей программе не является узком местом с точки зрения производительности. Вы можете бегать по матрице хоть 100 раз вместо 3. На производительность вашей программы это не окажет никакого влияния. Цель, к которой возможно стоило бы стремиться - это решить эту задачу без заведения такой явной матрицы вообще (да, одним-единственным циклом). Но это - совсем другая история.

Comment: У васа вывод не только в консоль, но и в файл, а тут никакие хитрости не помогут.

Comment: Как раз таки в файле нет проблем переместиться в начало файла, а вот в консоли это большой вопрос (есть конечно метод через consolehandle, но это не то, что хотелось бы). Я ожидал, что существует какой-то эскейп символ, по типу \n или \r, только на строку вверх. Странно, что так не бывает..

Comment: @AnT это лучше чисто синтаксически, но допустим у меня будет матрица не 6х6, а 1000000х1000000, пробег по такой матрице единожды занимает несколько секунд, что уж говорить о нескольких пробегах - вот моя мысль. А решение без массива впринципе я представляю, просто задача также требует вывода промежуточных результатов - изначальной матрицы, максимумов и ответа. И опять же, реализация без массива с этим требованием возможна, если есть возможность принтить по столбцам, но, как я понимаю - увы..

Answer (score 1):

По поводу вывода: нативными средствами возврата на строку назад добиться нельзя... Но, есть библиотеки, которые позволяют организовать подобный вывод в консоли. Я говорю об ncurses (она также компилируется под windows, но с этим могут возникнуть проблема, так что в этом случае используйте pdcurses - api тоже самое, за исключением редких моментов)